# delay in adding a contact using contacts framework in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, contacts, cncontactstore

I am using gthe following function to add a list of contacts (previously saved in NSData format). The contacts gets added however, it takes like a two minute delay before the confirmation message is displayed. At the first place, when I ran the app and i could not see the results, i thought there was something wrong and then I would closse the app but accidentally i waited once for 5 minutes and notices that contact was added and appeared in the address book.

- (void) recoverContacts: (NSData *)datacon
  {

  NSMutableArray *d2contact = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:datacon];
  CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

  [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      if (!granted) {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              // user didn't grant access;
              // so, again, tell user here why app needs permissions in order  to do it's job;
              // this is dispatched to the main queue because this request could be running on background thread
          });
          return;
      }
      else{

  ```
  // create contact

  CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
  CNMutableContact *contact1 = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
  contact = d2contact[1];

  contact1.familyName = contact.familyName;
  contact1.givenName = contact.givenName;

  CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
  [request addContact:contact1 toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];
  [sinformation setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hare Krishna Hare Rama!!!%@", contact1]];
   //save it

  NSError *saveError;
  if (![store executeSaveRequest:request error:&saveError]) {
      [sinformation setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hare Krishna Hare Rama!!!%@", saveError]];
    }
  }
  ```

  }];
  }